# Mutt: Saving a message as a text file

Tags: mutt

I would like to save a message in Mutt as a text file somewhere outside of my maildir. For example, `~/documents/notes`. I have found instructions for [Saving Messages to Files](http://therandymon.com/woodnotes/mutt/node17.html) which says that I should press either `C` or `esc-C` (depending on if I want headers or not) and then enter the directory I want to save to. When I do this and enter `~/documents/notes`, Mutt says: "/home/user/documents/notes is not a mailbox".

I want to save the message to a plain directory, not a mailbox. How can I do this?

Comment: Already answered in [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60838/saving-a-email-as-file-in-mutt).

Answer (score 13):

Use `C` (`copy-message`) or `<Esc>C` (`decode-copy`) if you want to save the mail as a mail message, necessarily in a mailbox. This mailbox can contain only one message if you want, but it won't be a `text/plain` file. If the mailbox (file or directory) doesn't exist yet, you shouldn't get an error: Mutt will propose you to create the mailbox.

If you just want to save the text of the body, then:

1. Type `v` (`view-attachments`).
2. Select the `text/plain` body (this is often the part that is selected by default, so that you won't have to do anything special here in most cases).
3. Type `s` (`save-entry`) to save the body to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this: Start a reply to the message  which will open the message in your chosen editor whereupon you can save what you have in your editor to a local file.